# Argument of type 'Promise<Modules>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: any) => Promise<Modules>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I have this helper function what I want to call after, with this signature   :

```
export const fetchPaginated = async <T>(
  callback: (params: any) => Promise<T>,
  {
    page = 1,
    pageSize,
  }: { page?: number; pageSize?: number; [x: string]: any },
  previousData = [] as Array<T>
): Promise<T | undefined>
```

I trying to use it this way:

```
...
fetchPaginated<Modules>(getModules({}), {}),
...
```

When I call it is shows me always the same error:

```
Argument of type 'Promise<Modules>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: any) => Promise<Modules>'.
```

I already tried to changes the types, but nothing fixed the error

Comment: Well `getModules({})` clearly is not a callback function. Don't change the types - change the argument!

Comment: Explicitly specifying type arguments to a function as in `fetchPaginated<Modules>(args)`, should be avoided in 99.9% of cases. When write a function, all type arguments should correspond to a value argument. In your case, they do so remove the explicit type argument from the invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Argument of type 'Promise<Modules>' is not assignable to '(params: any) => Promise<Modules>'
```

This means that `getModules({})`

- is not of type `(params: any) => Promise<Modules>`
- is of type `Promise<Modules>`

## More

Based on the error, it seems the fix will be:

```
...
fetchPaginated<Modules>(getModules, {}),
...
```